# Spaces in URL cause linkage failure

Tags: support, markdown

I can't get my URL to display properly. See the second link [after the jump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947693/creating-an-android-view-with-a-particular-style-programmatically). How can I fix this?

Comment: @S.Mark: It discussed parenthesis inside the URLS, not inside the URL title

Comment: no, this is an issue with URLs containing spaces, not parens.

Comment: sorry, I've deleted my dup link, his andriod.com url does have parens too, but wasn't aware that it because of spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resorted to using an <a> tag, but it looks like the second space being escaped to %20 would've worked.  (I caught one space, missed one, the first edit, which I then cleaned up within 5 minutes.)  I also changed the parens in the URL to %28 and %29, but, IIRC, that isn't required in the "outline" format you had originally.  Parens within the link text have always worked, AFAIK.

#### Test

[inline](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View%28android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int%29)
[outline](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View%28android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int%29)

```
[inline](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View%28android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int%29)  
[outline][1]

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View%28android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int%29
```