# Editor cannot handle URLs with spaces

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spaces in URL cause linkage failure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51914/spaces-in-url-cause-linkage-failure)

I tried to create a post on SO with three links,  2 of the links had spaces in them like this:
`http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/secure_hashing.html#Approved Algorithms`,  this broke all of the links on  the page.

To fix this issue I manually edited the layout and changed the space to a %20 like this:
`http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/secure_hashing.html#Approved%20Algorithms`.  This is a minor urlencoding fix that should be done in javascript.

Thank you.

Comment: pretty sure unencoded spaces aren't valid in URLs

Comment: @Jeff Atwood♦ your saying that a URL on the NIST website isn't valid,  and you are refusing to do a 1 line bug fix.  Or perhaps you just don't want to address this issue because its me,  and your ignoring the 300lbs gorilla in the room.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/are-urls-allowed-to-have-a-space-in-them

Comment: it is indeed invalid as a URL, but @Rook makes a really good point. Spaces would be sooo trivial to fix in the URL dialog. @Jeff

Comment: @Jon Seigel  @Jeff Atwood♦ @Pekka  you have to admire the irony of NIST breaking standards,  after all they are responsible for creating so many of them.

Comment: Small things like anchor names can easily slip through the cracks... I suppose you could make them aware of this issue if you want.

Comment: @Rook If you just enjoy being this way by all means keep it up, but if you post these bug reports actually desiring that they get fixed maybe you should try being slightly less abrasive? I knew what the comment tree on this post was going to look like before I'd finished reading the question

Comment: @Michael Mrozek I do enjoy being this way. Bug reports are a gift,  fix them and make the software better or ignore them and wallow in a cesspool.

Comment: If you're going to start fixing up invalid URLs in the link insert dialogue, there's lots more to do than just spaces. You'd probably want to use the `encodeURI` method to encode all non-URI-valid characters. (Does anyone really use the link button though, rather than just typing the link?)

Comment: @bobince yeah i use the link button,  and now i manually do a uriencode because the link button is broken. I phail :(